# Cancelled account linking leads to endless loop of same response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

If a user invokes my action, she is asked by google whether her account should be linked or not (something like: "If you want to use xxx, I got to link your account at xxx with google. Is this okay?"). Now, if she chooses "no", and my action returns an answer with `expectUserResponse` set to `false`, google assistant seems to jump into a very awkward endless loop of my returned response, even emitting the assistant's "conversation finished" sound after each response:

[image]
("In order to use xxx, I got to link your account at xxx with google. Is this okay?" - "No" - "Okay, this means you are not able to use your account at xxx. Get back to us if you change your mind.")

"Schönen Tag" (in the second speech bubble) is the response I am sending from my fulfillment.

[image]

So what we are getting here is an endless "Schönen Tag" - GoogleSound - "Schönen Tag" - GoogleSound - "Schönen Tag" - GoogleSound - Schönen Tag"- GoogleSound and so on. With no additional user input between each message. Imho, this definitely shouldn't happen, no matter if I configured sth wrongly or not.

I don't even need my fulfillment server to reproduce this. If I create a dialogflow intent, attach the `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` event to it and let this intent return a static response with "set this intent as end of conversation" set to true, I am able to fully reproduce this strange behaviour:

[image]
(this actually was the setup for all screenshots above)

If I recreate this intent, but change the setting to not end the conversation after sending the response, I do not get an endless loop anymore. But this isn't what I intended to do.

It also doesn't seem to matter if I require the sign in for explicit invocations or not (in the integrations-tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug, with a fix released this morning.

Are you still running into this issue?